# Try to find repetitive string in a pattern using findall() in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python to write a program that counts how many time a word appears. But, in order to count, the program needs to look at the beginning of a sentence and only count words in a sentence that starts with %. For example,

> %act:  <dur> pours peanut on plate

and I want to count the word peanut. The program should return 1. While,

> *CHI:  peanut.

would return 0 because it starts with *
So I used findall()

> findall('\%.*?' + "peanut", website_html)

But, if a sentence has two "peanut"'s, the pattern matching would only return 1. For example

> %act:  <bef> gives peanut . eats . <dur> gives peanut . <aft> gives raisin

would only return 1.

How can I make it return 2?

Thanks

Comment: What defines a sentence?  Can it span lines?

Comment: No, all of the sentences are only one line long

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend breaking it down into two parts.  I.e., something like:

```
num_peanuts = 0
for sentence in re.findall(r'(?m)^%.*', website_html):
    num_peanuts = len(re.findall(r'\bpeanut\b', sentence))
```

I'm not sure what the right regexp would be for selecting "a sentence that begins with "%" -- here I assume that it's a line whose first character is `%` (note that by default `.` does *not* match newlines; also, the `(?m)` puts the regexp in multiline mode; and the `^` is a zero-width assertion that matches the beginning of a line.).

I'll also note that the `\b`'s in my peanut-related regexp are to make sure that the word peanut is not a substring of some larger word (eg peanuts).  You may or may not want them, depending on the details of your task.

Comment: Thank you, Edward. I have another question. If I want to match both "butter" and "butter's" but not "butterfly", what patter matching should I use?

Comment: Here's one option: `r"\bbutter(?:'s)?\b"`  Again, the `\b` on either end ensure that it's not part of a larger word.  The `(?:'s)?` says to optionally allow a `'s` suffix.  (I use `(?:...)`, the non-grouping parentheses, rather than `(...)`, because the latter creates a group, which has special meaning to `re.findall`.  In particular, if a regexp contains groups, then `re.findall` returns the contents of the groups, rather than the matched strings.

Comment: To find a _line_ that begins with `%`, use `^...$` in multiline mode.

Comment: Is it possible to allow zero or one random char after the string "butter"?

Comment: @user1413230 Of course.  It sounds like you're pretty new to regexps -- I'd recommend finding and reading a tutorial about them -- google will give you many choices.  To match zero or one non-space character, use `\S?`, as in `r"\bbutter\S?"`.  You might also want `.?` or `\w?` or something else, depending on what you want included in "random character".

Comment: I would use [str.startwith](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) for finding the lines which begins with a %